# why numix icon theme get updates almost everyday?

Tags: updates, ppa, icon-themes

Everyday I open my pc and most of these days a Numix Icons update welcomes me? I'm starting to get suspicious about these. Is that a normal update cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get daily updates for the `numix-icon-theme` package simply because the project maintainers have set up daily builds for this package in their main ppa.

See https://code.launchpad.net/~numix/+recipe/numix-icon-theme-daily

It's not suspicious, just a bit unusual as most of the time daily builds are meant for testing in a separate ppa. Here the target of the recipe is the main ppa.