# apt-get upgrade downloads the same package every day

Tags: apt, package-management

I have the Numix icons package on PPA on Kubuntu 14.10.

That has been working fine, but a week or so ago an update came through, it installs and says complete I run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` that day and there are no updates available, but the next day it update appears back again.

I haven't been able to find anyone else with the same package problem, i.e. I don't think it is package related or there would be others with same issue.

```
Preparing to unpack .../numix-icon-theme_0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking numix-icon-theme (0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1) over (0.3+476~201507070101~ubuntu14.10.1) ...
```

I did try one thing delete the cache in /var/cache/apt/archives - but it didn't work and the post was slightly unrelated, will try again - if directed to correct cache file to delete?

I tried :

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

which didn't work, the package isn't held.
then after searching tried :

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Need to wait till tommorrow ?? ....

It is not the october 2014 change to the PPA as it has been working normally till July 2015.

Comment: what is the output for: `apt-cache policy numix-icon-theme`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why numix icon theme get updates almost everyday?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/536893/why-numix-icon-theme-get-updates-almost-everyday)

Comment: You should get ready to upgrade to 15.04. 14.10 will be dead before the end of the month.

Comment: numix-icon-theme:    **  
  Installed: 0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1
  Candidate: 0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Upgraded to 15.04, now I can't access my camera

Answer (score 3):

Look at the version numbers it says it's downloading to replace:

```
0.3+478~201507080101~ubuntu14.10.1
0.3+476~201507070101~ubuntu14.10.1
```

They *are* different. And looking at the full version, they look like nightlies (both built at 1:01 AM).

I suspect that if you look at `apt-cache policy numix-icon-theme`, you'll see you're getting it from a daily/nightly -style PPA, which tracks a development version control system and automatically recompiles the packages, regardless of change.

To stop this, either:

- Stop [remove (but don't purge) the PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/173199/449) (this alone won't uninstall the package)
- [Pin the package](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/449)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the package on hold. From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package), try to remove the hold of the package you want using

`sudo apt-mark unhold package_name`

Comment: It installs every day, so I didn't think it was that, muon says it is not held but incase :  
   
sudo apt-mark unhold numix-icon-theme
numix-icon-theme was already not hold.

Comment: does the installation of the package complete successfully?

Comment: Sorry problems learning formating  How do you line break???

Comment: In Muon it says the "new"package  version is installed but the "new" version is available for download (as an update)    
(I assume that means there is a config glitch)... No others programs are marked the same, so it is supposed to be installed....